# Postgres select distinct while sort specific value case

Tags: sql, postgresql

ticket_entries:

```
id | ticket_status_id
1  | 2
2  | 3
3  | 4
4  | 3
```

operate_logs:

```
id | ticket_entry_id | action_type | createtime
 1 |     1           |   2         | 2022-10-13 15:25:25.202417+00
 2 |     1           |   3         | 2022-10-11 11:25:25.202417+00
 3 |     2           |   3         | 2022-10-12 12:25:25.202417+00
 4 |     3           |   1         | 2022-10-14 15:25:25.202417+00
 5 |     4           |   3         | 2022-10-15 15:25:25.202417+00
```

I want to sort all ticket_status_id in (3,4) ticket_entry by their operate_log's create_time value whose action_type is 3, and those ticket_entry whose ticket_status_id not in (3,4) or dont have action_type = 3 operate_logs stay the last in result

the expected result should be

```
id | action_type
 4 |   3         
 2 |   3         
 1 |   2         
 3 |   4
```

I tried this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ( e.* ), o.create_time
FROM
    ticket_entries e
    LEFT JOIN operate_logs o ON e.ID = o.ticket_entry_id 
    AND o.action_type = 3 
ORDER BY
CASE
        
        WHEN e.ticket_status_id IN ( 3, 4 ) THEN
        1 
    END,
    o.create_time ASC NULLS LAST
```

the result says

```
ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 10: CASE
```

but this statement just works well

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (e.*), o.create_time
FROM
    ticket_entries e
    LEFT JOIN operate_logs o ON e.ID = o.ticket_entry_id 
    AND o.action_type = 3 
ORDER BY

    o.create_time ASC NULLS LAST
```

the relation between ticket_entries and operate_logs is **one to many**

what else should I select if I wanna make the sql work

Comment: Would be better to show both sample input and expected outcome than let people guess which query could eventually be useful or not.

Comment: Btw: putting parentheses around `e.*` is totally useless.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I actually tried select o.create_time ,  same error return

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think the problem is not with o.create_time but the case when phrase I use in sort

Answer (score 0):

Use a case expression that gets you the rows with status 3 and 4 and action 3 first and the others last. Then order these two data sets each by create_time.

```
SELECT e.id, o.action_type
FROM ticket_entries e
LEFT JOIN operate_logs o ON o.ticket_entry_id = e.id
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN e.ticket_status_id IN (3, 4) AND o.action_type = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
  o.create_time DESC NULLS LAST;
```